# Dominant root of a family of odd degree polynomials

Tags: polynomials, recurrences, differential-calculus, zeroes

Let $q$ be an odd positive integer and denote by $f_q(x)=x^q-x^{q-2}-1$. This family of polynomials appears in some problems related to recurrence sequences.

In order to try to use some standard methods in the theory, I must prove that $f_q(x)$ has a dominant root for all positive odd integer $q>1$ (clearly, this does not happen for an even $q$ since, in this case, $f_q(x)$ is an even function).

I already tried to use Rouché's theorem, Kakeya-Ernstrom method, positive matrices (hypergraphs and the Perron-Frobenius theorem). But, without success.

Any help is welcomed.

Thanks in advances...

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to prove that there is exactly one root $x_0$ in the real interval $[1, \infty)$ (in fact in $[1, 3/2]$), and $f_q(x) > 0$ for $x > x_0$.  If $r$ is any complex root with $|r| \ge x_0$, we'd have
$|r|^q \ge |r|^{q-2} + 1$. On the other hand, by the triangle inequality $|r^q| \le |r^{q-2}| + 1$, with equality only if $1$, $r^q$ and $r^{q-2}$ lie on the same ray.
 The only way to have $r^q = r^{q-2} + 1$ then is to have $|r| = x_0$ with $r^q$ and $r^{q-2}$ positive reals.  Since $r^2 = r^q/r^{q-2} > 0$, $r$ is a positive or negative real, but it can't be negative, else (since $q$ is odd) $r^q$ would be negative.
So we conclude that the only root with $|r| \ge x_0$ is $x_0$ itself.